# Scrolling in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I'm not asking how to do this, it's more in line of "What would you call this?".

I have an NSTableView with several custom cells. I want the table to scroll row by row, meaning that when I move the scrollbar up I want the top row to disappear and when I move it down I want the bottom row also to disappear - I don't want to see half my cell.

How do you call this type of behavior? And can you share some pointers if you've implemented it in a NSTableView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what this would be called (maybe something like "constrained scrolling"?), but you can do it using `NSView`'s `-adjustScroll:` method.

The general approach is that you need to make a subclass of `NSTableView` (if you don't already have one), and override this method to return a `NSRect` that has its `origin.y` value constrained to a multiple of your row height.

You probably also want to use `NSScrollView`'s `-setVerticalLineScroll:` to set the proper amount to scroll when the user clicks the scroll arrows in the vertical scroll bar.  You can get the scrollView by calling `-enclosingScrollView` on your tableView.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Let me test a bit before I accept the answer.

Comment: I was just trying to implement the same sort of behavior. I had some trouble where the bottom row could get cut off, so I increased the bottom `contentInset` of the Clip View by the row's height to counteract it.