# NSTableView Scroll Row By Row

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview

The app MacTracker has a list that scrolls in a "Row by Row" fashion:
[image: MacTracker scrolling]

How can I implement this in an NSTableView?

There's [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434991/scrolling-in-nstableview) from a while back, but I'd like to know how I can allow the top to be clipped at the bottom of the list if necessary

Comment: I have overridden `adjustScroll` that returns a multiple of the row's height, as suggested in that post, but the last row can get cut off at the bottom

Comment: Show lines of code for `NSTableView`.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments above, I mentioned I had used the recommended strategy from the old post (override `adjustScoll`, provide it with a multiple of my row height) but had trouble with preventing cells from getting cut off at the end

The solution I've come up with after experimenting was to increase the bottom of the Clip View's content inset by the height of a row.

Note that this does prevent you from clicking on the bottom row when it's not scrolled to the bottom, but for my needs, that's not an issue